# How to Create auto CloudFront invalidations in AzureDevops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-cloudfront

I have created Automatic invalidations in GitHub and it is working fine:

- run: aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id ${{ secrets.AWS_DISTRIBUTION_ID }} --paths "/fd/cm/latest/remoteEntry.js"

but not sure how to create the same task in AzureDevops. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

found the solution

- task: AWSCLI@1
  inputs:
  awsCredentials: "$$$"
  regionName: us-east-2
  awsCommand: cloudfront
  awsSubCommand: create-invalidation
  awsArguments: --distribution-id DistributionID --paths "/fd/cm/latest/remoteEntry.js"
  displayName: Cache Invalidation

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it the same way as @Visco suggested. Here is a screenshot of my **Task Group** to understand it better.

[image]